# Как конвертировать скринвидео из fbr

Tags: windows, видео, поиск-программ

Есть скринвидео в формате fbr, записанное [BB FlashBack Express](http://www.bbflashback.ru/BBFlashBack_FreePlayer.aspx).

Он поддерживает экспорт в avi, однако, встроенные кодеки заметно портят качество и увеличивают размер.

На данный момент нашёл весьма странный способ преобразования в avi с сохранением качества и примерно равным размером файла: сначала делается экспорт из fbr в avi без сжатия, затем в линуксе при помощи программы Transmageddon несжатый avi-файл пересжимается с кодеком h264 (никаких настроек там нет, всё делается с дефаултными параметрами).

Собственно, вопросы:

1. Какие программы (в том числе кодеки) нужно установить на чистый Windows 7 с установленным FlashBack Express Recorder'ом, чтобы можно было получить avi-файл примерно того же качества без промежуточного экспорта в несжатый avi?

   Программы должны быть бесплатными. Крайне желательно, чтобы было разрешено коммерческое использование.
2. Какие настройки следует выставить при экспорте из fbr?

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/31477/23135)

Comment: Можно на Youtube загрузить, а потом скачать :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, fbr? o_O Это ж собственный формат рекордера...

Comment: Рекордер это умеет делать сам, если верить их сайту.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, он и экспорт в avi умеет (надеюсь, не выпилили, а то свежая английская версия умеет только в wmv), но я не знаю, как настроить. Кодеки, которые там есть по умолчанию совсем не впечатляют.

Comment: Но при экспорте в Youtube он же, по-идее, должен использовать кодеки Youtube...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, меня всё равно вариант с ютьюбом не устраивает)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52112/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-pavel-mayorov).